# Как в recycler view (grid layout) сделать так, чтобы изображения были одной формы в виде квадрата?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, grid-layout

Как в recycler view (grid layout) сделать так, чтобы изображения были одной формы в виде квадрата?
Вот xml, c которым работает recycler view.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_margin="1dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tile_picture"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@drawable/city" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю нужно сделать картинки квадратными, но нужно знать максимальный размер! Для примера я проставил 20dp

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tile_picture"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@drawable/city" />
```

Comment: В одном ряду должны быть 3 одинаковые картинки по размеру